# Mock Azure cloud storage using NSubstitute and Xunit asp.net core, getting NULL for GetBlockBlobReference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, azure-cloud-services, nsubstitute

I have a below method and need to mock `CloudBlobContainer`

```
public async static Task<CloudBlobContainer> GetCloudBlobContainer(string containerName, IConfiguration configuration, bool isPrivate = true)
        {
            string storageConnectionString = configuration[AzureStorageConnectionStringKey];
            CloudBlobContainer container = null;
            containerName = containerName.ToLower();
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName); --> This is getting NULL
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            if (isPrivate)
            {
                await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });
            }

            return container;
        }
```

One of the method that implement `GetCloudBlobContainer`

```
public async Task<AssessmentCustomeDocumentDto> Upload(string fullFileName, long assessmentId)
        {
            var tenancyName = (await GetCurrentTenantAsync()).TenancyName;
            var blobContainer = await _azureStorageHelper.GetCloudBlobContainer(tenancyName);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileName) + "-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(fullFileName);
            var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            var tempProfilePicturePath = Path.Combine(_appFolders.SampleProfileImagesFolder, fullFileName);
            double fileSize = 0;
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(tempProfilePicturePath))
            {
                var bytes = fileStream.Length;
                double len = bytes / 1024;
                fileSize = Math.Round(len, 0);
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

            //// Other logics
            return new AssessmentCustomeDocumentDto();
        }
```

The  `var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);` is NULL

**Xunit test**

```
[Fact]
         public async Task Should_Upload_Assessment_Custom_Document()
         {
             var container = Substitute.For<CloudBlobContainer>(new Uri("http://legalregtechquestiondocs/"));
             // Other logics
             UsingDbContext(async
                 context =>
             {
                // Other logics
                 _azureStorageHelper.GetCloudBlobContainer("Tenant").Returns(container);

             });
             var _uploadDoc = await _assessmentCutsomDocumentAppService.Upload("xyz.doc", 1001);
             SaveChanges();
             // assert
             Assert.NotNull(_uploadDoc);
             Assert.Equal("xyz.doc",_uploadDoc.DisplayFileName);
         }
```

[image]

[image]

**Connection string in App Settings**

```
  "Azurestorage": {
    "AzureStorageKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "AzureStorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  },
```

Comment: Common reasons for GetContainerReference returning null include "blob container does not exist" and "there is a problem with the connection string". You code looks fine at a glance.

Comment: @ShahidSyed I am trying to mock the azure storage, why the connection string is required

Comment: My bad! I missed the context and was focusing on the GetContainerReference method. You need to setup substitution for blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference and all other method calls in the Upload method.